# yarn run: can I get the caller path?

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarn-v3

I'm using Yarn 3's workspaces.

If I have a script in a package.json

```
{
  "name": "myscripts",
  "scripts": {
    "migrate": "./migrate up -m src/migrations"
```

and in another package foo

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "dependencies": {
    "myscripts": "workspace:*"
```

if I run migrate from the foo package

```
yarn run migrate
```

is there a way to get the folder of the foo package in my migrate script?

I want to use the path in my migrate script `./migrate up -m $CALLERS_PATH/migrations`

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts what about $INIT_CWD documented here?

Comment: yes!!! I can't believe I missed that. I did a printenv and scanned for something useful. I'll mark it as correct if you add an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yarn docs here: https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts indicate that scripts are invoked with an `INIT_CWD` env var set to the original `cwd` the script was invoked from.

You should be able to (in a shell script for example), reference the path with

```
./migrate up -m $INIT_CWD/migrations
```